# Dashboard filter for data sources with different objects

Tags: dashboard, filters

I have a large dashboard with info on Cases. This dashboard can be filtered by the Case Record Type field and this is good. Also, I have a custom object with some additional data which is explicitly related to cases. What I want is to put a component with this custom object to the dashboard and make sure that it is filtered by the same Record Type field.

I added record types with the same names to the customer object, and also I tried to create a custom field with the same name for both Case and the custom object, but no avail. Salesforce does not understand that these fields of Case and the custom object are the same and does not allow to apply the filter for both data sources.

Is there a way to achieve my task and have a working dashboard filter for data sources with two different objects?